# mongodb insertion shows 'strings in documents must be valid UTF-8'

Tags: python, mongodb, utf-8

this is my code

```
        for code, data in dict_data.items(): 

            try:
                collection2.insert({'_id':code,'data':data})

            except Exception as e:
                print code,'>>>>>>>', str(e)
                sys.exit()
```

it exited with

```
         524715 >>>>>>> strings in documents must be valid UTF-8
```

I could find out the error only by the try catch method. dict_data is a large dictionary which contains calculated values from other collection.

how can i fix this?

thanks

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or Python 3.x ?

Comment: I am using python 2.7.5

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PyMongo and Python 2.x, you should use str in utf-8 or unicode strings. See:
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#a-note-on-unicode-strings

If `data`is a dict with multiple strings you can convert all of them to unicode using following function:

```
def convert2unicode(mydict):
    for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, str):
            mydict[k] = unicode(v, errors = 'replace')
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            convert2unicode(v)

for code, data in dict_data.items(): 
    try:
        convert2unicode(data)
        collection2.insert({'_id':code,'data': data})
    except Exception as e:
        print code,'>>>>>>>', str(e)
        sys.exit()
```

Previous code will convert all str values in unicode, the "keys" keep untouched, depending on root cause you should also convert the "keys".

Comment: Rec, data is a large dictionary in which many strings will be there. How is it possible to provide unicode for all those strings???

Comment: I've updated my answer in order to use a helper function to replace all str values in the dict

Comment: @ManikandanV, if the answer solved your question, please consider to mark it as "accepted".

Comment: @SRC No, the unicode values are replaced in the input param `mydict` (`data`)