# Trying to save data after reading .p12 file into mongo gives me Error

Tags: mongodb, google-drive-api, pymongo

Trying to save .p12 private key file for a service key account for domain wide delegation gets me an error.

```
Exception: Illegal params - strings in documents must be valid UTF-8
```

What I am trying is while uploading the file, read the content and then store it in the mongo db.
I tried `bson.Binary`, `unicode`, `str(utf-8)` etc. But some way its giving problem.

Any ways to properly do this ?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474701/mongodb-insertion-shows-strings-in-documents-must-be-valid-utf-8

Comment: Thanks MFB, I finally resolved the things by just encoding with some base64 and then encrypt it so as its consumable by Mongodb